# Remotely Enable Wakeup from Shutdown

Tags: powershell, wake-on-lan

I am trying to get 400 pcs setup to wake on lan.
everything is enabled on all the pcs but one check box.
Under the advanced tab on the nic, "wakeup from Shutdown" is disabled
and I need to enable it on all pcs.

I have a working script to change the boxes under the power management tab but those are already checked. but I cant seem to find any info about anything under the advanced tab. properties on nic, configure, advanced)

Any help in figuring out if this is possible would be a big help.
Could I edit that code to just enable what I need? or simpler to write a new one?

I haven't tried anything cause I cant seem to find any info as to if this is even possible.
im thinking its just a different wmi object (probably wrong name) but in my code that works I found the lines that go to each check box and am wondering if there is a class for "wakeup from shutdown"

*** line im curious about

```
foreach ($NIC in $NICs) {
    $Errors = $false
    Write-Host "NIC:"$NIC.Name
    #Allow the computer to turn off this device
    Write-Host "Allow the computer to turn off this    device....."      -NoNewline
    ***$NICPowerManage = Get-WmiObject MSPower_DeviceEnable    -Namespace root\wmi | Where-Object { $_.instancename -match [regex]::escape ($nic.PNPDeviceID) }
    If ($NICPowerManage.Enable -ne $TurnOffDevice) {
        $NICPowerManage.Enable = $TurnOffDevice
        $HideOutput = $NICPowerManage.psbase.Put()
    }
    If ($NICPowerManage.Enable -eq $TurnOffDevice) {
        Write-Host "Success" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    } else {
        Write-Host "Failed" -ForegroundColor Red
        $Errors = $true
```

OTHER LINES

```
Get-WmiObject MSNdis_DeviceWakeOnMagicPacketOnly -Namespace root\wmi | Where-Object { $_.instancename -match [regex]::escape($nic.PNPDeviceID) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this little tool called `WMIExplorer.exe` to navigate WMI. I think `MSPower_DeviceWakeEnable` is the class you are looking for.

After a few searches, I stumbled upon this. Perhaps that is similar to your problem.
https://www.itinsights.org/Enable-wake-on-lan-WOL-with-PowerShell/

[image]

Comment: I actually found that before posting this. but I appreciate it. I tried running it again with everything off. and it only messed with options under power management tab. im thinking there isn't a wmi for "wake from Shutdown"

Comment: @davidweaver What you are trying to do is change settings of BIOS. This largely depends on the BIOS provider of your target machines. Since you are targetting PCs, perhaps look for a namespace of the manufacturer. (I know HP, Dell and Lenovo provides their own). If they are VMs, the provider would be VMware etc. They should have a class you can use. It is not evident on the picture but WMIexplorer will help you look at the methods and properties of the classes too.

Comment: no the bios is set just fine. its literally just one tick box under the advanced tab that says wake on shutdown. and after I tick that wol works just fine. but im going to dig through that app though and see what I can find

Comment: @davidweaver Also look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/enable-netadapterpowermanagement?view=win10-ps